# Prove that there is a differentiable function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfying $[f(x)]^5+f(x)+x = 0$

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, functional-equations

> Prove that there is a differentiable function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfying $$[f(x)]^5+f(x)+x = 0$$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Find $f'(x)$.

Seeing how this is a functional equation, I think we might be able to use induction or some other technique to determine information about $f$. We have that $$f(0)\left([f(0)]^4+1\right) = 0 \implies f(0)  = 0$$ How might else we find a way to find $f'$ or to prove that it exists?

Comment: You said: We have that $f(0)([f(0)]^4+1) = 0 \implies [f(0)]^4  = -1$. 
That should be $f(0)=0$ or $[f(0)]^4  = -1$, but the latter is impossible since $f(0)$ must be real. So $f(0)=0$.

Comment: Hint for the existence: Define $\phi:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ by $\phi(t)=t^5+t$. Then $\phi'(t)\ge1$ for all $t$, which implies that $\phi$ has a (continuously differentiable) inverse function...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Such a function $f$ is simply the inverse of $g(x) = -x^5 - x$, which is monotonic and differentiable with $g'(x) = -5x^4 - 1$ nonzero everywhere. Hence $f$ is differentiable everywhere by the inverse function theorem, and $f'$ is given by the chain rule.

Comment: Right use of inverse theorem! +1

Comment: How do you find $f$? Do we use that $(f^{-1})^{'}(f(x)) = \frac{1}{f'(x)} \implies \frac{1}{-5x^4-1} = f'(x)f(x)$?

Comment: @anomaly How do you find $f$?

Comment: What do you mean? $f$ is the inverse of $-x^5 -x$; that's really all you can say about it.